# How to access relational db in database locator in KTM

Tags: ocr, kofax

I can create connection to sql server db but unable to use that in KTM's database locator. All I can use is localFuzzyDataBase which is not actually a relational db. 
How to connect to relational db (sql server) in KTM's database locator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database locator works with fuzzy databases only. You cannot use a relational DB.

Comment: yes Daniel, found that. locator name is misleading though.

Answer (score 0):

If you use KSMS (Kofax Search and Matching Server) you can use a relational database as a fuzzyDB : 
- install KSMS,
- create and activate a DB in KSMS
- link you DB locator with the remote fuzzydb